How to use Typed IHttpClientFactory with Autofac (using .NET 8)?
I am trying to use Typed HttpClient with Autofac. But I couldn't able to make it work.
public class MainViewModel
{
   public MainViewModel(MoviesApiClient moviesApiClient, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
   {            
   }
}


public class MoviesAPIClient
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public MoviesAPIClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5001");
    }
}

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddHttpClient<MoviesAPIClient>(configureClient =>{});
  var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
  return provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
});

 builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
 builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().AsSelf();
 return builder.Build();


Can someone suggest the Solution to make it work?

See https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting and https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#startup-class. Also, building one off service providers to get around and misunderstanding of di containers is and all too common source of bugs. Basically, it's wrong in 99.9% of cases.

I fixed it by returning with right Typed Client "MoviesAPIClient"
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddHttpClient<MoviesAPIClient>(configureClient =>{});
  var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
  return provider.GetRequiredService<MoviesAPIClient>();
});


Take the time to read the docs - you very much should not mix and match containers like this.
